# UITableView application crashes when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Firstly, please forgive my English.

I am learning about iPhone SDK, Obj-C and trying to make UITableView app. But my app crashes when scrolling the table. I've searched but can't solve my problem, so I post my question here and look for your help.

TMTMemberListTableViewController.h

```
@interface TMTMemberListTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *familyMembers;
    sqlite3 *database;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *familyMembers;

- (void) configureCell:(TMTFamilyMemberCell *)cell withFamilyMember:(TMTFamily *)member;

@end
```

TMTMemberListTableViewController.m

```
@interface TMTMemberListTableViewController (Private)
    - (void) loadMemberListFromDatabase;
@end

@implementation TMTMemberListTableViewController

@synthesize familyMembers;

- (void) loadMemberListFromDatabase
{
    familyMembers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"easycook.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "SELECT member_id from family";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *memberID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                TMTFamily *member = [[TMTFamily alloc] initWithMemberID:memberID database:database];
                [familyMembers addObject:member];
                [member release];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self loadMemberListFromDatabase];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [familyMembers count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    TMTFamilyMemberCell *cell = (TMTFamilyMemberCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[TMTFamilyMemberCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    TMTFamily *member = [familyMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Set up the cell
    [self configureCell:cell withFamilyMember:member];
    [member release];
    return cell;
}

- (void) configureCell:(TMTFamilyMemberCell *)cell withFamilyMember:(TMTFamily *)member
{
    cell.familyMember = member;
    cell.memberNameLabel.text = member.description;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc");
    [familyMembers release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When scrolling table, my app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at

```
[self configureCell:cell withFamilyMember:member];
```

and

```
cell.memberNameLabel.text = member.description;
```

Comment: I suggest running Product->Analyze from the Xcode menu and fixing any problems it reports.  I'm reasonably sure that you shouldn't be releasing `member` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but I can't tell whether there are other places like that.  (Also, consider converting to ARC.)

Comment: Are you suer `member` is retained by `[self configureCell:cell withFamilyMember:member];` so you have to release it?

Comment: you don't own `member`, don't release it

Answer (score 1):

This line is not incrementing retain counter:
`TMTFamily *member = [familyMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

So the following line is your problem 
`[member release];`

You cannot release object if you down't own it. Either retain it like that:
`TMTFamily *member = [[familyMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];`

or

`TMTFamily *member = [[familyMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] copy];`

or remove mentioned `release` completelly.

Comment: there is no need for the `retain` here, better to just get rid of the `release`

Comment: After remove 'code'[member release] line my app still crashes :(

Comment: I hope you removed second [member release] and not the one in `loadMemberListFromDatabase`?

Comment: Do you pass `MyIdentifier` to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`? Where is it crashing now? Please add general breakpoint for all exceptions to see it.

Comment: Finally, I fixed my bug. My bug is not in two file posted here, it is in init() method of my TMTFamily class. When set value for description property, instead of using self.description, I assign value to description directly. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great that you have found your problem. As a general rule you should avoid using accessors in `init/dealloc`. It may cause side effects.

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow and welcome to the world of iOS Development.

There are a bunch of problems with your code and if you have an Apple developer account, I highly suggest you head over to the 2012 WWDC Session Videos and look at the talk about Modern Objective C session.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

Looking at the code, your bad access could either be an already released object or an empty cell.  To determine the cause, you need to enable NSZombies.  To do so, click on your project name in the tool bar as shown here:

[image]

In this example, it's called PartialTransparentcy (spelling be damned).  When you click that button, click the edit scheme button and you'lll see a list of options.  You'll want to click enable Zombie objects.  If you don't see it, press the Diagnostics tab.

[image]

Then run your code and it'll log the object that is giving your grief.  Just remember that zombie objects are very expensive.  If you submit an app with them enabled, you'll be automatically rejected.

The first thing I notice when I look at your cell initialization code is this:

```
TMTFamilyMemberCell *cell = (TMTFamilyMemberCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

You are sending in a nil identifier which negates that whole entire point of reusing cells.  Instead, you are creating a new cell for each row instead of reusing older cells.

So uncomment this line:

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
```

and change the dequeue method to read like this:

```
TMTFamilyMemberCell *cell = (TMTFamilyMemberCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
```

If you are building your cell in interface builder, you'll need to also give the cell an identifier.  This may be the cause of the crash.

Next ... your sqllite code should be encapsulated in another object.  There's no reason for the view controller to know about it.  Also, you should really investigate core data.  It defaults to sqllite backing store.  It's also a pretty awesome technology.

And finally, take a look at ARC. Let the compiler handle the grunt work of memory management so that you can focus on the user experience of your application.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: I want to up-vote this answer because of how awesomely friendly it is! Unfortunately, this is likely not the reason for the crashing, it is as Tomasz says, a simple memory management issue

Comment: Thanks for your kindness :D After enabled Zombie Object, I received message means I am trying access to dealloced memory.

Comment: I also tried to move sqlite code to AppDelegate class but nothing was fixed, my app still crashes :(